# What is up with the HUGE .yarn/ folder in new Rails 6 apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, webpacker

First of all the .yarn/ folder is nowhere to be found in .gitignore.

Second it's HUGE which makes it difficult to do backups.

What's up with this? Shouldn't this folder be in ~/ instead?

Comment: What are the contents of this directory? can you `ls` it and show us a sample of its contents?

Comment: It's so big StackOverflow won't accept it. Nor will it accept a pastebin link in the main post, so here it is: https://pastebin.com/XKmmLiSC

Comment: Hello @TamerShlash?